# Counting a column's first name

Tags: mysql, sql, string, count

MYSQL - How to count the first name of each line? I have a customer table that has a column with the full name of the customer. I need to know the number of characters in each customer's first name

```
------------------------
|  table client        |
------------------------
| id | name            |
------------------------
| 1  | Dylan Smith     |
| 2  | Bruce Johnson   |
| 3  | James Williams  |
| 4  | Thomas Johnson  |
| 5  | Jimmy Jones     |
| 6  | Matthew Miller  |
------------------------
```

I need the query to return the following:

```
id | qtd_caracte
1  | 5
2  | 5
3  | 5
4  | 6
5  | 5
6  | 7
```

Does anyone know how this is possible? already searched on google and did not find.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `substring_index()`:

```
select t.*, char_length(substring_index(name, ' ', 1))
from t;
```

Note this conveniently works even if the `name` does not have a space, which is why I suggest it over `position()`/`instr()`/`locate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use string functions:

```
select id, char_length(substring_index(name, ' ', 1)) nb_car
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the function [`LOCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to get the position of the first space:

```
select id, 
       locate(' ', name) - 1 qtd_caracte
from client
```

If there is a case that the name does not contain a space:

```
select id, 
       locate(' ', concat(name, ' ')) - 1 qtd_caracte
from client
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2381c8fa3fc325970c8212f3fb3fa6d2).
Results:

```
> id | qtd_caracte
> -: | ----------:
>  1 |           5
>  2 |           5
>  3 |           5
>  4 |           6
>  5 |           5
>  6 |           7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, char_length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1)) AS `qtd_caracte` from client ;
```

Enjoy...

Comment: (char_length())